# How to iterate through two lists of different length and then save only those values which are not similar in a new list

Tags: python, arraylist

```
array1 - [40, 30, 20, 10]
array2 -[40, 30, 40, 20, 40, 10, 30, 40, 30, 20, 30, 10, 20, 40, 20, 30, 20, 10, 10, 40, 10, 30, 10, 20]
```

I want to iterate `array2` through `array1` in the following index order:

`array2{0}(40)`->`array2{1}(30)`->`array2{0}(40)`->`array2{1}(30)` and then move to: `array2{2}(40)->...` repeat the same thing till you get to the end of `array2`. And while this is happening, it's going over each elements of `array1` and looking for any non similar values (`20`,`10` here), this gets saved in a new array.

Here `{}` are `[]`.

Comment: Hi @Colt_Rigs, why you are repeating first two array elements two time - array2{0}(40)->array2{1}(30) and than again array2{0}(40)->array2{1}(30). How you are comparing to get the similarities between this  two array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, what you want is iterate over the arrays, two by two (pairs), each time comparing the pair from the array 1 with the pair from the array 2, to determine if it counts as a ifference, in which case you will return all the differing pairs at the end.

(I used an `itertools` recipe, available in [its official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools-recipes), or in the [`more_itertools`](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/more_itertools/recipes.html) library)

This is my proposal :

```py
from itertools import zip_longest

from more_itertools import grouper


def compare_arrays(a, b):
    differences = []
    # we start by grouping each list by twos, and zipping them together
    for pair_a, pair_b in zip_longest(grouper(a, 2), grouper(b, 2)):
        # print(pair_a, "|", pair_b)
        if pair_a is None or pair_b is None:
            break  # if the lists have not the same length, it does not count as a difference
        elif pair_a != pair_b:
            differences.extend(pair_a)
    return differences


array1 = [40, 30, 20, 10]
array2 = [40, 30, 40, 20, 40, 10, 30, 40, 30, 20, 30, 10, 20, 40, 20, 30, 20, 10, 10, 40, 10, 30, 10, 20]
print(compare_arrays(array1, array2))
# [20, 10]

array1 = [20, 20, 30, 40, 50, 50, 60, 70]
array2 = [20, 20, 30, 00, 50, 00]
print(compare_arrays(array1, array2))
# [30, 40, 50, 50]
```